# Trying to install openssl on windows with php.ini file

Tags: php

I'm trying to install Laravel, and I have to install openssl. I followed the steps, and edited the php.ini file, and uncommented the correct line. So, when I run the Laravel installation, it says

```
A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
```

What should I do?

I changed the php.ini-development file to php.ini, and uncommented there; should I modify the php.ini-production file?

If anyone knows how to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so just found the answer:

on my php.ini file, I had changed the `;extension = php_openssl.dll` to `extension = php_openssl.dll`, but didn't change the `extension_dir = ".\"` to `extension_dir = "ext"`

That solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

is there any solution of this problem

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

if you run into this problem, check that you also uncommented the extension_dir line not just the extension=...dll line.
; extension_dir = "ext" -> extension_dir = "ext" (on windows)